# I need to use a function from a non standard compiled library

Tags: c

i have a problem that i hope you can solve, i have to do a homework in c but the teacher requested us to use a function that is in a non standard compiled library (it have an .a extension) that he made and sent to us, so i wondered how can i use it (i mean how can i compile my program in a way that it can use the compiled library that he sent us). I will make an example.

If i know that i have a function called mult, which is as follows.

```
int mult(int a, int b) {
return a * b;
}
```

But it's on a compiled library called mult.a, what do i have to write in the source code?, what do i have to write in the Makefile?.

I know how to use makefile to use more than 1 source code, .h or .c files to make a program, but never had to use an alredy compiled file.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An .a file is an object file archive. When you link your program you can simply add the file to the input list:

```
# compiling:
gcc -c -o main.o main.c

# linking:
gcc -o main main.o teachers.a
```

Comment: @OiciTrap you're welcome!  Please consider to accept my answer if it solved your question. Click on the check mark left of an answer to accept it.